# Json java. Parse to string

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Как правильно парсить данный json.

```
{
 "results" : [
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "45",
           "short_name" : "45",
           "types" : [ "street_number" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "проспект Aль-Фараби",
            "short_name" : "проспект Aль-Фараби",
           "types" : [ "route" ]
          },
          {
             "long_name" : "Бостандыкский район",
              "short_name" : "Бостандыкский район",
             "types" : [ "political", "sublocality",            "sublocality_level_1" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Алматы",
           "short_name" : "Алматы",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Казахстан",
           "short_name" : "KZ",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "проспект Aль-Фараби 45, Алматы, Казахстан",
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 43.2249503,
           "lng" : 76.93780819999999
        },
        "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 43.22629928029149,
              "lng" : 76.9391571802915
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 43.22360131970849,
              "lng" : 76.93645921970848
           }
        }
     },
     "place_id" : "ChIJkVDDqCNvgzgRXHOe5BavjiE",
     "types" : [ "street_address" ]
  },
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "Бостандыкский район",
           "short_name" : "Бостандыкский район",
           "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Алматы",
           "short_name" : "Алматы",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Алматинская область",
           "short_name" : "Алматинская область",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Казахстан",
           "short_name" : "KZ",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Бостандыкский район, Алматы, Казахстан",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 43.2426069,
              "lng" : 76.99433329999999
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 43.037215,
              "lng" : 76.83271409999999
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 43.1641072,
           "lng" : 76.9297354
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 43.2426069,
              "lng" : 76.99433329999999
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 43.037215,
              "lng" : 76.83271409999999
           }
        }
     },
     "place_id" : "ChIJfe4i2c9ogzgRg1Pdg9Caozc",
     "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
  },
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "Алматы",
           "short_name" : "Алматы",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Карасайский район",
           "short_name" : "Карасайский район",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Алматинская область",
           "short_name" : "Алматинская область",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Казахстан",
           "short_name" : "KZ",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Алматы, Казахстан",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 43.4057021,
              "lng" : 77.1467686
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 43.0287453,
              "lng" : 76.7415618
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 43.2220146,
           "lng" : 76.8512485
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 43.4057021,
              "lng" : 77.1467686
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 43.0287453,
              "lng" : 76.7415618
           }
        }
     },
     "place_id" : "ChIJq8vFFn1ugzgRdm2YrY9mRD0",
     "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
  },
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "Казахстан",
           "short_name" : "KZ",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Казахстан",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 55.4419839,
              "lng" : 87.315415
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 40.5685841,
              "lng" : 46.4936719
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 48.019573,
           "lng" : 66.92368399999999
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 55.4419839,
              "lng" : 87.31538399999999
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 40.5685841,
              "lng" : 46.493672
           }
        }
     },
     "place_id" : "ChIJR6n87AcQqTgRGw6z5C-Ee18",
     "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
  }
 ],
 "status" : "OK"
}
```

Хотел бы с данного Json файла вытащить строку "formatted_address". Никак не получается.

Делаю запрос в гугл, для декодирования, чтоб получить Адресс места, куда тыкнул маркером. Вот мой код:

```
private String getUrl(LatLng address_latlng) {
    String latlng = address_latlng.latitude + "," + address_latlng.longitude;
    String parameters = "latlng=" + latlng;
    String output = "json";
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/" + output + "?" + parameters;

    Log.e("getUrl", ">>>>>>>>>" + url);
    return url;
}


private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Reading data from url
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();
        Log.d("downloadUrl", data.toString());
        br.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
    } finally {
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
}

private class FetchUrl extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        String data = "";

        try {
            // Fetching the data from web service
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            Log.d("Background Task data", data.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();
        parserTask.execute(result);

    }
}

private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        JSONArray arr = null;
        try {
            arr = new JSONArray(jsonData[0]);
            JSONObject jObj = arr.getJSONObject(0);
            String date = jObj.getString("formatted_address");
            Log.d("LOG.D", " " + date);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {


    }
}
```

Comment: вам нужна только одна строка из всего json или нет?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman да

Comment: тогда рассмотрите идею использовать регулярные выражения.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman там в массиве как я понимаю три варианта даётся, мне нужно как-то достать "formatted_address" с нулевой позиции.

Comment: вот пример https://regex101.com/r/4d9Z8x/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто разобрать JSON и достать нужное значение. Простейший вариант:

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
    String address = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("formatted_address");
    Log.e("address", address);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("ERROR", e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
```

Короткая запись:

```
try {
    String address = new JSONObject(data).getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getString("formatted_address");
    Log.e("address", address);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("ERROR", e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
```